# Заменить текст после определяемого слова Java

Tags: java, replace

есть строки допустим:
`appel.name=Appel`
`hello.name=Hello`
`potato.name=Potato`
Мне нужно после равно (=) во всех строках заменить, чтобы получилось так
`appel.name=Яблоко`
`hello.name=Привет`
`potato.name=Картошка`
PS: работа будет происходить с большим текстом, просто replace("Appel", "Яблоко"); не поможет.

Comment: Через регулярные выражения сделай.

Answer (score 0):

Не самое правильное, но простое. Не правильно, потому что в такой задаче по хорошему должен быть словарь, хотя бы в виде `Map<String, String>`, чтобы можно было однозначно сопоставить. Сейчас оно будет работать, только в том случае если список **list** и **rusWords** будут одинакового размера и совпадать по порядку

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("appel.name=Appel");
    list.add("hello.name=Hello");
    list.add("potato.name=Potato");

    List<String> rusWords = new ArrayList<>();
    rusWords.add("Яблоко");
    rusWords.add("Привет");
    rusWords.add("Картошка");

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String s = list.get(i).replaceAll("\\w+$", rusWords.get(i));
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```